# When I update my data, it reverses the results of my Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report that I pull directly from our database (Query), but it includes more information than necessary (items with no values), so I added a Subroutine to delete the rows that were extra. The Subroutine seems to work fine to correct the empty rows. I then have another Subroutine that copies the values returned and puts them below onto another sheet where the header is already laid out, and then another to add the signature block on the bottom. When this is all complete, the user makes a copy of this sheet and renames it for the month and year that it applies to. This would be a finished and easy process, but......

The problem is that when the workbook data is refreshed to create a new report, all prior copies of formatted and finished reports suddenly include the rows that were deleted. I don't understand how deleted rows return to reports on different sheets, but here is the VBA i'm using to accomplish this. (I have since set this up to run automatically upon updating the data, but I get the same result)

Hopefully, someone can help, thanks for any help in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim lr As Long, i As Long
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    With wb1.Sheets("DATA SHEET")
        lr = Application.Max(.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row, _
          .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row)
        For i = lr To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 4).Value = 0 And _
              .Cells(i, 5).Value = 0 And _
              .Cells(i, 7).Value = 0 And _
              .Cells(i, 8).Value = 0 And _
              .Cells(i, 9).Value = 0 And _
              .Cells(i, 10).Value = 0 Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is the VBA to copy the data over, which was just a recorded Macro. I need to keep my formatting, but didn't see how to only transfer values and formatting.

```
Sub CopyToTemplate()
'
' CopyToTemplate Macro
'

'
    Rows("3:100").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("SAVE TEMPLATE").Select
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please include your code for querying the database and for copying from the base data to the formatted report? The issue is more likely in one of those or the interaction between them.

Comment: This is the code to transfer the data to the second page Sub CopyToTemplate()
'
' CopyToTemplate Macro
'

'
    Rows("3:100").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("SAVE TEMPLATE").Select
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
End Sub

Comment: Please [edit] the additional information into the question post. You're more likely to get useful answers, the easier you make it for people to understand your problem and its context.

Comment: I think I know what it is. You mentioned my original query, and that's probably the issue. When I run the original query, it populates my data, then I manipulate it and save it on another sheet. Then I run another query, and it ruins the manipulated data on all sheets. I think that query is staying connected to the data on all sheets and repopulating with new data. Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you are copying cells that are automatically linked to your data query. Because you are copying the entire cell, the link is coming with it.

To copy only the value and formatting, replace

```
Range("A7").Select
Activesheet.Paste
```

with

```
Range("A7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("A7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is documentation on PasteSpecial.

Comment: Isaac, thanks for the documentation, I am totally new to VBA and appreciate a reference. This is giving an error though. It doesn't like the first line, and I'm not sure how to rearrange it to fix.

Comment: @DavidTinsley Sorry about that. What error did you get? I changed the paste command to paste to the range instead of to the sheet, which ought to work. I didn't account for the fact that PasteSpecial is a method of a range, not a sheet.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. It is no longer responding to query updates, and works beautifully. You're Awesome!